# SBS2008 migration to 2012R2 Foundation possible?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

is it possible to migrate an sbs2008 to 2012R2 Foundation?
Exchange and Sharepoint are no longer needed.
I just need the AD structure so I do not need to edit the client systems.

I am a bit unsure because of the Foundation Version of 2012.

Thank you very much

Comment: A little tip from me: the wsus server is unavailable version in the Foundation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meet the [license standards](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892(v=ws.11).aspx), you should be able to do this.  If I were you (and I'll be doing something similar very soon), the steps I would take are:

1. Perform a full backup of the SBS08 server and test it.
2. Upgrade the schema of the SBS08 server to support 2012 R2 domain controllers.  (You can either do this with the command line or using 2012 R2's [new wizard](http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/upgrading-active-directory-windows-server-2012-r2#/0).)
3. If you're not using the wizard, promote the 2012 R2 machine to be a domain controller.
4. Allow the servers to replicate for a while while you migrate other things you might be using off the SBS08 server.
5. As the last step of migrating off the SBS08 server, [transfer the FSMO roles to the new server](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/02/10/step-by-step-migrating-windows-server-2003-fsmo-roles-to-windows-server-2012-r2/).

After performing step 5, you might as well switch the SBS08 server off because you're in violation of your license and it's about to start rebooting to point this out.  If you find problems and need to turn it back on, you might want to transfer the FSMO roles back while you work.

Good luck!

Comment: I´ve done the migration two days ago without any Problems. Is the schema Update nessesary?

Comment: It looks like it's included in the new wizard.  "In Windows Server 2012 and R2, Microsoft has gone a step further and streamlined and integrated the ADPREP forest and domain upgrades and DCPROMO domain controller promotion processes into one Active Directory Domain Service Configuration Wizard that takes care of everything." http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/upgrading-active-directory-windows-server-2012-r2#/0